# Configure check for threadsafe errno

Tags: c, errno

We had a problem report in our software that turned out to be caused by a non-threadsafe-`errno` (thanks to slightly wrong compiler flags on Solaris).

I'd like to add a configure check to ensure that this bogus mode of operation doesn't sneak back in again.

I started with something fairly naive:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* thread1_func(void*)
{
    errno = 1;
    return 0;
}

int
main ()
{
    errno = 0;
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1_func, NULL);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    return errno;
}
```

This works well on most platforms, except on OpenBSD where `return errno` produces 2 - even though `pthread_create`/`pthread_join` don't touch `errno`. (Hilariously, this goes away if I insert a `printf` call before `pthread_create`, which made debugging this quite difficult.

I suspect accessing `errno` in this manner is technically undefined.

How can I check if `errno` is threadsafe?

Comment: I'm not asking if pthread functions set errno, nor whether errno is threadsafe (that answer is only correct under certain conditions) - I want to know how I can check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* thread1_func(void*)
{
    errno = 1;
    return 0;
}

int
main ()
{
    errno = 0;
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1_func, NULL);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    return errno;
}
```

is not a valid test for `errno` values or usage.  Per [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **7.5 Errors <errno.h>**, paragraph 3:

> ... The  value  of `errno` may  be  set  to  nonzero  by  a  library 
>   function  call whether  or  not  there  is  an  error,  provided  the 
>   use  of `errno` is  not  documented  in  the description of the
>   function in this International Standard

In other words any function is free to modify the value of `errno` if the C standard doesn't explicitly say that it can't, even if there is no error.

`errno` is only valid immediately after a library function call that is documented to use `errno` has returned an error.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought! How can I test if errno is threadsafe?